# How can I output a UTF-8 encoded XML file with unix line-endings from ActivePerl on Windows?

Tags: perl, unix, file, winapi, utf-8

I'm running ActivePerl 5.8.8 on WinXP. I'd like to output an XML file as UTF-8 with UNIX line endings.

I've looked at the perldoc for [`binmode`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/binmode.html), but am unsure of the exact syntax (if I'm not barking up the wrong tree). The following doesn't do it (forgive my Perl - it's a learning process!):

```
sub SaveFile
{
    my($FileName, $Contents) = @_;

    my $File = "SAVE";
    unless( open($File, ">:utf-8 :unix", $FileName) )
    {
        die("Cannot open $FileName");
    }
    print $File @$Contents;

    close($File);
}
```

Comment: I'm curious as to why you care about line endings. XML doesn't care. Whatever you read the file back in with shouldn't care either.

Comment: What are you intending to achieve with `my $File = "SAVE";` ?

Comment: @AmbroseChapel: I agree, we shouldn't care but the (Library Management System - Ex Libris' Aleph) software that sucks it up is finicky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $Contents does not already have `\n` characters, `print` will not add them for you.  You must do that yourself.

There's a couple other things that might be problematic; here's how to fix them and why.

[IO Layers](http://perldoc.perl.org/PerlIO.html)

To enable utf8 output, you need to use `:utf8`, not `:utf-8`.  In addition, you should not have spaces in your IO layers, so it should look like `">:utf8:unix".

[Open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html)

To `open` a file, you can declare the 'my $fh' in line; no need to initialize it to a string to start.  It's okay, this is good practice.  In addition, using `or` is the preferred way to catch open errors.

Changed around, your code looks like this now:

```
sub SaveFile
{
    my($FileName, $Contents) = @_;

    open my $File, ">:utf8:unix", $FileName
        or die "Cannot open $FileName";
    print $File map { "$_\n" } @$Contents;

    close($File);
}
```

[map](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/map.html) lets you transform your input array by adding the newlines to each line before it prints them, and does it in order.

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I think you need something like this.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub save_file {
    my ($file_name, $content) = @_;
    open my $fh, ">", $file_name or die $!;
    binmode $fh, ':utf8 :unix';
    print $fh @$content;
    close $fh;
}

# For example.
save_file('foo.txt', [ map "$_\n", qw(foo bar baz)]);
```

For typical use of the 3-argument form of `open`, you want the file handle variable to be undefined before calling `open`. See [the docs](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) for details.

Comment: This outputs UTF-8 but not UNIX line endings in my XP environment.

Comment: @Umber Ferrule Not sure what the problem is. It works for me on XP, including Unix newlines. Here's a dump of the file: `666f 6f0a 6261 720a 6261 7a0a`.